# jquery show/hide not working on wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, show-hide

I have a site i'm working on http://trueproperty.org/ and on the front page i have two divs, one is `#excerpt` and the other is `#content`. #content is filled using
`<?php the_excerpt(); ?> <button id="readmore">Continue Reading...</button>`
and #excerpt is filled using
`<?php the_content(); ?>` .

## content is set to `display:none`. now i use this code to display #content and hide #excerpt when the user clicks continue reading, it works in [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/uyawen), but not on the [actual site](http://trueproperty.org/), and i cant figure it out :/.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#readmore").click(function(){
            $('#content').show('slow');
        $('#excerpt').hide('fast');
 });
});
            </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loading two files that uses `$` as alias ..

The following works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#readmore").click(function(){
        jQuery('#content').show('slow');
    jQuery('#excerpt').hide('fast');
});
});
        </script>
```

But it would be better to look for the conflict issue and use `jQuery.noConflict`

Comment: also what @Nadir Muzaffar says is true

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't seem like you reference the Jquery library before you actually use the jQuery object. Try placing the code after the:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://trueproperty.org/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.1' />
```

Answer (score 0):

Place this code at the end of `Head` tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#readmore").click(function(){
     $('#content').show('slow');
     $('#excerpt').hide('fast');
   });
 });
</script>
```